# The various definitions of adjoint

Tags: linear-algebra

Mathematics appears to have many different definitions of adjoint. There are adjoint representations on Lie algebras, adjoints of a matrix, adjoint actions on the space of linear transformations.  Are they really about the same thing?  If not what is common to them?

Answer (score 1):

As with most deep definitional things in mathematics, one naturally turns to Category Theory for some insight. I believe the definition of adjoint given [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/adjunction) generalises those you mention above (although quite notably I don't think adjoints in *infinite* vector spaces fit this description, their finite counter-parts do).

You also might want to check out the related answer given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1010353/675062).